# How do you include same-font variants in html?

Tags: html, fonts

I've downloaded Montserrat font and want to use it in html using:

```
<link rel="preload" href="your_font_file" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

But can we include several variants here? Italic, medium, regular..

I suppose there is an option to repeat that link on each style.

Comment: Do you require the complete set of normal, medium, boild, italic for a particular reason? I only ask because if you're using the font just as a font to style your site (rather than say something like a font-download site where they need all the examples), could you simply organise any italics and stuff in the normal way with CSS?

Comment: But the css will need to import those anyways, right? @CuteCodeRob

Comment: Yes you would have to 'install' the font correct or it might not appear for some people if they do not have that font installed on their computer. But then, once the font is installed hopefully it can be styled in the regular way like all other text. Have you tried using GoogleFonts? Take a look, very easy to do and you can be assured that it will always show correctly.

Comment: I want them locally for speed @CuteCodeRob

Comment: Would that be local to you though because that doesn't mean local for me and so at my end the performance may be different.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob true

Comment: Sorry @minsky ... I'm babbling. Eyes inside too many tabs. Your way of doing it will be fine and there won't be a performance thing at my end. I still recommend Googlefonts though :)

Comment: Added answer @CuteCodeRob your conjecture makes sense anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid google fonts or a font delivery network, it seems what they do is to preload a css file with font src declarations.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

if you plug that link to the browser, you get:

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v23/JTUHjIg1_i6t8kCHKm4532VJOt5-QNFgpCtr6Xw0aXpsog.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v23/JTUHjIg1_i6t8kCHKm4532VJOt5-QNFgpCtr6Xw9aXpsog.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
....
```

and many more.

So You can preload the CSS with that line. The webfont generators give you the css for the font (just upload the ttf and convert to web font).

A nice one is https://transfonter.org/.

Mind that as it was stated in the comments you won't necessarily improve UX as the request to a google font is likely to be cached and may be quicker.